# Can I safely do a backup of Windows after cleaning it from malware?

Tags: windows, installation, backup, virus, malware

Long story short, I accidentally installed some malware on my PC. I immediately reached for MalwareBytes Anti-Malware and it detected 4 files: trojans and spyware. I removed it. Then I proceeded to do additional check-up with Avast (is there a better free AV, btw?), ADWCleaner, MS Security Essentials, HitmanPro and Spybot. All of these programs displayed 0 detected malware.

And here comes my question: is it safe to create a backup image after that? Or is my PC still infected? I really don't want to do a clean install of Windows, as it would be too much hassle atm.

Comment: If you trust it's clean, then you trust it.  If not, then format and start over. As-is this isn't really something we can answer for you beyond opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a judgement call, depending on factors such as what happened with the infection, how long you had it for, what kind of symptoms you experienced, etc... but generally you should have a strong bias against **ever** trusting an installed operating system once it's been infected. Your safest course is usually to back up your data and re-install your system from the bare metal up.

In this case, you know what you did and you acted immediately. A little bit of research on the specific types of malware and you *may* be okay, provided there isn't some rootkit hanging out in the background logging keystrokes or similar.

That said, I would still add at least one more precaution before continuing to use this system, especially for anything involving real money like online purchases or banking, or that could be used to establish your identity, such as e-mail or even social networking. Use a boot disk or temporarily move the hard drive to a different machine so that you can scan the disk from a known-clean operating system. You don't want to trust the scan results reported to you by an infected OS.

Comment: How can I scan for rootkits? And could booting Windows to Safe Mode make it easier?

Comment: Safe mode isn't good enough. You need a clean OS, which means connecting the drive as a guest disk in another computer or using a stand-alone boot disk/scanner. If you don't already know what you have, you probably want to re-install.

Comment: Alternative: Boot from a "rescue cd" and run a scan. I usually opt for f-secure's - https://www.google.se/search?&q=free+rescue+cd